# MySQL Get rows that only exist in one table performance

Tags: mysql

The basics of this query have been asked, and answered, many times before, but I'm still having trouble with performance. Here are the details:

I have the table, Products, that has 105724 rows.
I have an update table, _e360products, that has 51813 rows.
I am matching on an alphanumeric 10 character code, that is indexed (unique) on both tables.

I have tried:

```
SELECT _e360products.Product_Code, products.StockCode
FROM _e360products Left Join Products ON _e360products.Product_Code = Products.StockCode
WHERE products.StockCode IS NULL
```

and:

```
SELECT Product_Code 
FROM _e360products
WHERE Product_code NOT IN (SELECT StockCode FROM Products)
```

and, just for a laugh, even:

```
SELECT Product_Code
FROM _e360products 
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM Products WHERE StockCode = Product_code) = 0
```

None of these have returned results within 20 mins!

If I reverse the queries, i.e. getting unique rows from _e360products, I get results very quickly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

~~~~~ Update ~~~~~
Explain results are:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref                                      | rows  | Extra                                |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | _e360products | index  | NULL          | Product_code | 12      | NULL                                     | 50811 | Using index                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Products      | eq_ref | stockcode     | stockcode    | 12      | plumbase_bkup._e360products.Product_code |     1 | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+

CREATE TABLE `_e360products` (
  `Product_code` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Manufacturers_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Supplier` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Price` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `VAT` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `Analysis_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_code`),
  KEY `Product_code` (`Product_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `QPUM2` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `NWID` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NHEI` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NLEN` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `donotdisplayprice` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `productname` text,
  `stockcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `analysiscode` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `usestockcontrol` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `stockvalue` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_notification_level` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `sectionid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `productprice` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `productprice_incvat` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `deleted` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`productid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `stockcode` (`stockcode`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `allowordering` (`allowordering`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=147440 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

NoteL Products table doesn't include ALL the fields, as there are quite a few...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a query execution plan (EXPLAIN), it seems your index is not used. Also show as CREATE TABLEs for both tables.

Comment: Additional info added, and problem found... while both Product_code and Stockcode were varchar(10), Product_code was UTF8 characterset and Stockcode was latin1 characterset - make them both latin1 (or UTF8), the query restins results immediately!

Answer (score 1):

Typo? StockCode[add space here]IS

```
SELECT _e360products.Product_Code, products.StockCode
FROM _e360products Left Join Products ON _e360products.Product_Code = Products.StockCode
WHERE products.StockCode IS NULL
```